# Why do some TIPS bonds have credit spread < 0

Tags: fixed-income, bond, credit-risk, bond-yields, yield

If we look at the yield spreads on Bloomberg of some TIPS bonds, we see they have credit spread < 0 (i.e. their yield is even lower than their benchmark treasury bonds)

Why is that the case. Shouldn't treasury bonds typically have the lowest yield? How does TIPS work to have lower yield than treasury?

Comment: You should __not__ interpret the yield spread between the TIPS and benchmark bonds as a credit spread.
See [this question and answers](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/what-does-the-yield-spread-between-an-inflation-linked-treasury-bond-tips-and)